# Not one in a hundred thousand

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Life is so terrible, it would have been better not to have been born. Who
is so lucky? Not one in a hundred thousand!*

I am not sure whether "a hundred thousand" is related to people or to years. I presume that the former alternative is more probable. But woldn't it be better to say "not one from one hundred thousand"?

Comment: I agree that it's people. We use "x in x" with numbers when referring to frequency/statistics. "1 in 10 people think..." etc.

Comment: Is there a source for this? It is really depressing...

Comment: @user3169 https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52302/8572

Comment: The quote exemplifies antinatalism: https://www.reddit.com/r/antinatalism/.

Answer (score 2):

> Not one in a hundred thousand!

answers the question

> Who is so lucky?

The subject is *who*, so it follows that the number refers to people (being born). Consider:

> Not one (person) in a hundred thousand!

You could tack on *years*, but at best it is an assumption as there is no related context.
Besides *a hundred thousand years* is a really long time. Maybe three people to date.

Comment: And there's no mention of years in the quote. Rule of thumb: Don't assume that a "back reference" like a pronoun or, as here, an assumed subject, is referencing a thing or idea not previously mentioned in the text unless that's the only way to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase

> Not one in a hundred thousand!

is speaking about **people** due to the **Law of Proximity**(1), the closest association is with the previous line

> Who is so lucky?

The preposition **in** is used since it is a **frequency observation** within a **population**, and is used in **probability statistics**

> (number of observations) **in** (total size of population)
>
> 10 students **in** the class were used for the test

The preposition **from** can be used when individual values are **taken** from a **set of values** with or without replacement

> names were drawn **from** a hat
>   10 students were taken **from** the class

(1) The **Law of Proximity** is not a law *per se*, but is generally understood